# Error in drool file: input mismatch

Tags: drools

I am working on a drool file with the below code:

```
    rule "test rule"
    @RuleNumber(1)
    @RuleMessage("data mismatch")
when
    $myObj : MyObj($localVal1: val1)

    $dataMismatch: Boolean() from ($localVal1 == null) 
    eval $dataMismatch
then
   //do something
end
```

I keep getting the error mismatched input '$dataMismatch' in rule, Parser returned a null Package

Does anyone know where am I going wrong?

Thanks!

Comment: Not your problem, but the syntax of the `eval` CE requires parentheses. Check the manual.

Answer (score 0):

Unless you get paid by lines of code written, you should use:

```
rule "test rule"
@RuleNumber(1)
@RuleMessage("data mismatch")
when
  $myObj : MyObj(val1 == null)
then
  //do something
end
```

(Looking into syntax errors cannot be done reliably without knowing the Drools version, which you haven't provided.)